# show data if status is published only and save only when status is draft in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have used this code:

```
    public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
{
    $query = parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted);

    return $query->where('status', 'Published');
}
```

this code only shows the published data in frontend and backend.

I want to show the data of draft in admin portion only but not in frontend..

do i have to know first that is this page admin or fronend first?if so, then how to do??

please reply..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it out:

```
public function newQuery($excludeDeleted = true)
    {
        $query = parent::newQuery($excludeDeleted);
        if(Auth::check() && (!Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')))
                return $query->where('status', array('Published','Draft'));

        else
              return $query->where('status', 'Published');

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can get the route name using this code

```
Route::currentRouteName()
```

After getting route you need to set an condition like

```
if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'frontent'){
   return $query->where('status', array('Published','Draft'));
}else{
   return $query->where('status', 'Published');
}
```

I think this procedure will work.I am not sure.Please try this

Comment: @sabinmaharjan where is the problem?